# Como alterar a pasta padrão de uma aplicação ASP .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Estou tentando configurar um site ASP .NET Core, para hospedar uma aplicação AngularJS.

A estrutrura que a minha página "index"está usando é:

```
/wwwroot/app/index.html
```

Eu tentei algumas configurações no arquivo Startup.cs, como essa:

```
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "app"))
            });
```

E também tentei a seguinte configuração no método Main:

```
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "app"))
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

Mesmo com ambas as configurações acima, eu ainda preciso navegar na URL http://localhost:PORTA/app para renderizar o arquivo Index.html.

Eu quero que o arquivo Index.html seja renderizado quando eu navego para a URL root http://localhost:PORTA/

**EDIT:**

Acabei de achar a solução. É necessário adicionar isso na chamada do WebHostBuilder:

```
    .UseWebRoot(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "app"))
```

Comment: Adicione uma resposta para sua própria pergunta, creio que pode ser útil para mais pessoas.

Comment: Você já tentou mexer nas regras de roteio da aplicação?